# FFMPEG in Bash - Too many inputs specified for the "movie" filter

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

Basically, I am doing a script to automate video watermarking, border insert, and noise adding.

When I use the following combination:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "$INPUT" -vf "noise=alls=$NOISE_INDEX:allf=t , movie=$WATERMARK [watermark]; [in]scale=512:trunc(ow/a/2)*2 [scale]; [scale][watermark] overlay=$OVERLAY_SETTINGS_WATERMARK [out] , drawtext=text=$TEXT:$OVERLAY_SETTINGS_TEXT:fontsize=32:fontcolor=black:box=1:boxcolor=white@1: boxborderw=5 , pad=iw+50:ih+50:iw/8:ih/8:color=red" $OUTPUT
```

...it shows the following error:

```
Too many inputs specified for the "movie" filter.
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
```

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the movie filter. Use `-i` instead:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "$INPUT" -i "$WATERMARK" -filter_complex "[0]scale=512:trunc(ow/a/2)*2[scale];[scale][1]overlay=$OVERLAY_SETTINGS_WATERMARK,noise=alls=$NOISE_INDEX:allf=t,drawtext=text=$TEXT:$OVERLAY_SETTINGS_TEXT:fontsize=32:fontcolor=black:box=1:boxcolor=white@1:boxborderw=5,pad=iw+50:ih+50:iw/8:ih/8:color=red" "$OUTPUT"
```

Using the movie filter like that is an outdated, legacy method from many years ago.